# Lambda function: why do I need a parameter in eventhandlers but not in Button-commands?

Tags: python, lambda

In the following case of a Python lambda call, I need to set a parameter for the function to work properly:

```
name = Entry(self.new_jobtile, width=30)
...
name.bind('<Return>', lambda x:self.create_tile(name.get()))
```

However, if I use a Button instead, the very same lambda call works without the "x" parameter:

```
Button(self.new_jobtile, text="OK", command=lambda: self.create_tile(name.get()), width=4, height=2).pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=3, padx=5)
```

I really don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can create lambda function without arguments:

```
bar = lambda : 4*2
bar() # 8
```

I do not know what library are you using but I think that in `name.bind` second argument should be function with one parameter (like `lambda x:` or `def foo(x):`) but in `Button` constructor argument `command` should be function with 0 parameters (like `lambda :` or `def foo():`).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about API of that `Entry` and `Button` classes, but here is my guess. Probably `bind` method of the `Entry` requires a callback function (your lambda) to has one parameter, in other words, somewhere in the `bind` method can be a piece of code like this:

```
def bind(self, an_argument, yourcallback):
    yourcallback(something)
```

You just ignore this parameter, but you can figure out what that `bind` method passes to your callback:

```
name.bind('<Return>', lambda x:self.create_tile(str(x) + " " + name.get()))
```

From the other side, the `pack` method does not pass a parameter. So your lambda works in that case.